# What were the names of the seven rings of power held by the Dwarves in LoTR?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

The seven rings were given to the dwarves of seven clans: Longbeards, Firebeards, Broadbeams, Ironfists, Stiffbeards, Blacklocks, Stonefoots. What were the names of the rings given to them?

Comment: I don't believe there are any direct references to the names of the Dwarf rings of power. In-universe the Dwarves are pretty insular and secretive. Gandalf mentions they have words in the "Dwarf tongue that they teach to no one". If the rings had names I think it would be unlikely the names would be shared with others. Whether or not the rings had names prior to being given to the Dwarf lords is also unanswerable due to lack of information.

Comment: @Withywindle But there's no reason that others, such as the Elves, could not have names of their own for those rings. Not saying they *do*, but, they *could*

Comment: I have no idea how you found all clan-names and not that there are no names for these rings...

Comment: Each ring had a different effect on the wielder's personality. Each ring was named for their effect. In the Dwarf tongue their names mean: The Healer, The Discontented One, The Joyous One, The Sleeper, The Hidden One, Sneezy, and Dopey.

Comment: @Mithoron I wasn't able to find the names of the rings, so I assumed maybe there was some resource which listed it that I couldn't find.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**No names are given for either the Nine or the Seven**

Throughout the Lord of the Rings and other related material (including the essay *Of the Rings of Power and the Third Age* in the Silmarillion) only the Three Elven rings are given names.

In *Of the Rings of Power and the Third Age* the fact that the Three were different to the others is specifically called out:

> Now these were the Three that had last been made, and they possessed the greatest powers. Narya, Nenya, and Vilya, they were named, the Rings of Fire, and of Water, and of Air, set with ruby and adamant and sapphire; and of all the Elven-rings Sauron most desired to possess them, for those who had them in their keeping could ward off the decays of time and postpone the weariness of the world. But Sauron could not discover them, for they were given into the hands of the Wise, who concealed them and never again used them openly while Sauron kept the Ruling Ring. Therefore the Three remained unsullied, for they were forged by Celebrimbor alone, and the hand of Sauron had never touched them; yet they also were subject to the One.

In fact these Three were also the only rings that the Elves saved from Sauron; he had successfully captured all of the others, and those captured rings were the ones he gave to the other races:

> But Sauron gathered into his hands all the remaining Rings of Power; and he dealt them out to the other peoples of Middle-earth, hoping thus to bring under his sway all those that desired secret power beyond the measure of their kind. Seven Rings he gave to the Dwarves; but to Men he gave nine, for Men proved in this matter as in others the readiest to his will.

The only indication of anything that may be a name used for any of the Dwarf rings is given at *the Council of Elrond*:

> The Seven are lost to us – if Balin has not found the ring of Thrór which was the last; naught has been heard of it since Thrór perished in Moria.

But "ring of Thrór" could not possibly be it's original name because it was given to the Dwarves in the Second Age, millennia before Thrór lived.

To summarize:

- No names are given for any rings other than the Three.
- There is no reason to believe that any other rings had names.
- While they certainly *could* have done so, the fact that the Three are special and different is constantly called out.
- Dwarf rings *may* simply be named for the current (or last-known) holder, e.g "ring of Thrór" (remember that only Gandalf knew that Thrór had given his ring to his son).

Comment: A minor quibble, not all of the seven had been captured by Sauron, some where lost to dragons instead.

Comment: As usual, please consider [merging](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist) your accounts! You'd have an immense amount of reputation racked up with great priveleges

Comment: Thrór's ring was originally given to Durin III.

Comment: @bp. he captured all of them from the elves and gave them to the dwarves. Then it turned out they didn't work very well so he then tried to get them back again later.

Answer (score 4):

The elves named their rings.  We were given no reason to believe any of the others had names though.

Comment: This seems more appropriate as a comment.